# UITableViewCell - Text and background image are displayed based on last cell's attributes

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

In my app, designing for iOS7, I have a grouped UITableView. Each row displays some text entered by the user. I calculate the row height based on the length of the text in each row. Each row also got same background image, but stretched using resizableImageWithCapInsets based on the height of the row.

Below is my code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.currentChatView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:
                                         @"CurrentText"];
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CurrentText";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.currentChatView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
                             CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    UIImage *cellImage;
    UIImageView *cellImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    UILabel *cellLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];

    cellLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cellLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    cellLabel.text = [[self.textArray 
                       objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"text"];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"aqua.png"];
    UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(image.size.height/2, image.size.width/2, 
                                           image.size.height/2, image.size.width/2);
    cellImage = [image resizableImageWithCapInsets:insets];
    cellImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 215, cellHeight + 5);
    cellLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, 200, cellHeight);

    cellImageView.image = cellImage;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:cellImageView];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:cellLabel];

    return cell;
}
```

Table row heights are calculated and displayed correctly. However, the text and background are shown based on the height calculated for the last row.

For example, if the 2nd row got two lines of text and the last row got only one line,  then the second row is displayed with a height for 2 lines, but only the upper half of text and image are displayed in the row. The lower half of the row is empty with white background. The last row is displayed correctly.

Similarly, if the last row has two lines of text, then the image background of all rows are stretched to fill two lines of text.

I am not sure what the cause is and couldn't find a solution anywhere. Your suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: If `cellHeight` is supposed to be different for each cell, why is it not declared and calculated _locally_ in this method?  Also, the code is creating and adding `cellImageView` and `cellLabel` even if a cell is being re-used (which will already have those views) so you end up with duplicates stacked on top of each other.

Comment: Anna, cell height is calculated in section given below, which is the right place to calculate it. (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath. As stated in question, all cells are displaying correct heights.             There is no chance to duplication here (and no concept of reuse in the app either).

Comment: Please show the code for heightForRowAtIndexPath.  The duplicate subviews must be getting added as you scroll the table view and bring previously displayed cells back on the screen (the UITabelView reuses their views).

Comment: May be I wasn't clear enough... My initial load itself got issue. No issue with cellHeight or the selection of text in it (no matter whether I scroll or not). The background image for all cells is always stretched for the size of last row (image is correct, but not strecting). Also, the number of lines of the text is displayed based on how many number of lines are in the last row. (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath got just one line of code to calculate cellHeight based on text length. This overrides Apple's default cell height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out... The cell heights for all rows are precomputed in `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

By the time to control arrives at `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I have the last cellHeight.

The best solution is to assign imageView and label frame sizes in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you use an instance variable `cellHeight` to store the cell height for each row, and it is not updated when needed. You can try to use `(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` to get cell height dynamically in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`.